# How can is resolve warning of variant.getPackageLibrary()

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any solution to resolve this warning for now in my code, as its showing the reason 'The Kotlin plugin is currently calling this API. We are working to solve this.'

**WARNING: API 'variant.getPackageLibrary()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageLibraryProvider()'.**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 28
   defaultConfig {
     minSdkVersion 15
     targetSdkVersion 28
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
   }
}

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${kotlin_version}"
 }
```

Comment: Did you resolve that? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

set the latest version of kotlin in `kotlin_version` then rebuild the project.

Comment: I am using      ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30' and Android Studio version is 3.4.0